# Exchange reply all copying sender

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013, activesync

**Symptom:**

Users sending emails in Outlook or on a mobile device connected via ActiveSync or Outlook Anywhere reply all to an email message.  The sender ends up also being copied on the reply as well as having it show up in the sender's Sent Items.

The user mailboxes are on 2013 and also use Lync 2013, so they have SIP addresses in their list of valid PrimarySMTPAddress values.

How can we prevent the sender from getting copied on messages they "Reply All" to?  This doesn't occur when connected via OWA.

Answer (score 3):

*I ran into this yesterday and figured others might want to see this in the future.  Didn't see this particular issue listed on SF.*

This seems to be a known issue.  See here:  [Senders receive a message copy after they click "Reply to All" in Exchange ActiveSync](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3012580).

They state a workaround as:

> To work around this problem, manually change any existing address that is not the Primary address to all-lowercase characters.

This change fixed the users having the issues without ill side-effects.

Comment: My current client ran into this exact issue recently, after we changed the primary SMTP domain for all users but not all OCS SIP addresses had been fixed up yet. I didn't even think of posting it; thanks! I was embarrassed that it was our Telecom manager that found the KB article, I had really been assuming it was a new iOS bug.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to hit the user with something hard and blunt, then ask them to only bother me with actual problems, but I suppose YMMV.